# KVO NSKeyValueObserving

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, key-value-observing

I want to make Observing for NSString of Custom class.

//add

```
[self.sourceUser addObserver:[self appDelegate] forKeyPath:@"uJid" options:0 context:nil];
```

//remove

```
[self.sourceUser removeObserver:[self appDelegate] forKeyPath:@"uJid" context:nil];
```

In app Delegate I use

```
- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"uJid"])
    {
       //     self.iHopeItTemp = object       
    }
}
```

But I not get it, Why? How Can I get new parameter of my object?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `didChangeValueForKey` you need to use `observeValueForKeyPath`. Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html) for an example.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"uJid"]) {
        // your code
    }
    /*
     Be sure to call the superclass's implementation *if it implements it*.
     NSObject does not implement the method.
     */
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
```

Comment: If it's not working, then you need to actually generate some KVO notifications for the property change.  Invoke `-[NSObject willChangeValueForKey:]` and `-[NSObject didChangeValueForKey:]` and see if that does the trick.

Comment: @Merlevede, I create [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"messageVC.user.uJid" options:0 context:nil]; in mapVC for property messageVC but then I adn I get observeValueForKeyPath. Then I move observeValueForKeyPath to appDelegate I not get it with [self addObserver:[self appDelegate] forKeyPath:@"messageVC.user.uJid" options:0 context:nil]; in mapVC

Comment: The error is in the first `self`, you're not adding an observer to self, but on your mapVC, so you should replace `self` with your `mapVC` instance.